# Number of occurrences of strings in array

Tags: python, algorithm, strings, array, hash-map

*This is a Hackerrank problem (https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/sparse-arrays/problem)*.

We're given an array of strings and an array of queries, and have to return an array of the number of occurrences of each query in the array of strings.
For example: s = ['ab', 'abc', 'aba', 'ab']. q = ['ab', atr', 'abc]. We need to return [2, 0, 1].

The constraints are `1 <= n <= 1000`, `1 <= q <= 1000`, where `n` and `q` are the number of strings and queries respectively, and `1 <= |strings[i]|, |queries[i]| <= 20`.

**Here is my code**:

```
def matchingStrings(strings, queries):
    results = []
    dic = {q:0 for q in queries}
    for s in strings:
        if s in dic: dic[s] += 1
    for q in queries:
        if q in dic: results.append(dic[q]) 
    return results
```

Is there anything I can optimize? Speed, memory usage? Anything else?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

- `if q in dic` is pointless. You initialized `dic` so that it does have all queries.
- `dic = dict.fromkeys(queries, 0)` should be a bit faster.
- `dic` is not a particularly meaningful name, `counter` or `ctr` would be better.
- Creating `results` at the start of the function gives the false impression that it's needed there already. I'd create it right before the loop that builds it. Then you'd have the complete counting part first, and the complete querying part afterwards. Or better yet, ...
- ... use a list comprehension, which is faster and nicer.
- Python already has a `Counter` class that does a lot for you and is probably faster.

```
from collections import Counter

def matchingStrings(strings, queries):
    ctr = Counter(strings)
    return [ctr[q] for q in queries]
```

For fun: 1000*1000 isn't super big, and HackerRank's calling code really only needs an iterable, so... this also gets accepted:

```
def matchingStrings(strings, queries):
    return map(strings.count, queries)
```

Comment: I'll buy that a list comp is nicer, but faster? That's more difficult to claim. I'd enjoy looking at a profile.

Comment: @Reinderien It's common knowledge and I've done that comparison too many times. Since you apparently never have, I encourage you to do it now :-)

Comment: @Reinderien Btw, after seeing some people claim that list comprehension is *always* faster, a while ago I even *tried* to find a case where it isn't. I thought maybe I could relatively slow down the list comp by using outside variables so it would be a more expensive lookup or so. I failed. Whatever I tried, list comp was always significantly faster.

Comment: Without diving into a profiling session myself, there is ample evidence that some comprehensions are slower; take https://stackoverflow.com/a/27906182/313768 for instance.

Comment: @Reinderien Sure, if you artificially slow them down like that with something you're not doing in the loop version. But can you show a *proper* comparison where they're slower?

Answer (score 8):

Any time you are using a dict, and you need to do something special the first time a key is used, take a look at [`collections.defaultdict()`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict).

```
from collections import defauldict

def matchingStrings(strings, queries):
    results = []

    counts = defaultdict(int)
    for s in strings:
        counts[s] += 1

    results = [counts[q] for q in queries]

    return results
```

Any time you need to count things, take a look at [`collections.Counter()`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/collections.html#collections.Counter).

```
from collections import Counter

def matchingStrings(strings, queries):
    counts = Counter(strings)
    return [counts[q] for q in queries]
```